# Unmet Dependancy Error while installing new package

Tags: elementary-website, package-management

I was trying to install elementary-tweaks using the instructions from their github [page](https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks).

I first did a
`sudo apt install software-properties-common`.

Then `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks && sudo apt install elementary-tweaks`

Which got me this error :

```
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
elementary-tweaks is already the newest version (1.0-0~202010170103~ubuntu6.0.1).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 elementary-tweaks : Depends: libgranite5 (>= 0.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have tried several solutions from this askUbuntu [page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716915/dpkg-error-processing-packages-cannot-complete-install-desktop-gui-from-termina) but it didn't help.

Comment: The ```apt --fix-broken install``` doesn't help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

elementary-tweaks are not supported in 6.x versions of elementaryOS. You should be installing pantheon-tweaks from https://github.com/pantheon-tweaks/pantheon-tweaks.